# I'd like to search CoreData records, over many fields

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I'd like to perform an NSFetchRequest. I want to look through all objects with a specific NSEntityDescription, but just look for text in *all* the fields in that entity.

I'd like to do this, because I want to have a simple search field in my app. So if a user types in "Joe Cincinnati", they would expect to get back all records that have the text "Joe" and "Cincinnati", regardless of which fields they show up in. Also, the record must have both "Joe" and "Cincinnati" in their fields somewhere, it just doesn't matter where.

Comment: Do you have any specific issue ? What are the results of your research ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without designing specifically for this kind of search, you're stuck with either using complex multi-part predicates or with doing repeated fetches to cover each search term/string attribute pair. For `M` search terms and `N` string attributes you end up with either one predicate with `M x N` components or doing `M x N` separate fetches. Both of these options suck.

But with some advance work you can sidestep that issue. Here are a couple of options to consider:

**Add a new "searchText" field to your entity**

Add a new string attribute to your entity description called `searchText`. This field is made up of all the text from every other string attribute, but in a normalized form (e.g. lower case) in a single location. Any time data in another string field changes, you update `searchText`. When searching, you only use this attribute. Your predicate has the same number of components as the number of search terms, which should be much faster.

In this case your predicate would be a compound AND predicate where each term's format is something like `@"searchText contains %@"`.

Or...

**Add a new "SearchText" entity**

Create a new entity type called `SearchText`, which has a single string attribute. Set up a one-to-many relationship from your current entity type to the new `SearchText` type. Each instance of your entity type will relate to one `SearchText` instance for every possible search term. This still requires a multi-part predicate, but since the text field is much shorter the results should be much faster.

In this case you still have a compound AND predicate, though in this case each part's format would be something like `@"any searchStrings = %@"` (assuming the new to-many relationship is called `searchStrings`).

Comment: Thanks, Tom. I think I'll use part 1 of your answer. Sounds good and simple.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe would be a rather extensive predicate, but you can create a generic solution by examining the `NSEntityDescription` and iterating over the attributes. You can check the type as you only care about strings. For each string you should create a predicate. Then you can create a compound predicate from them.